# Calculation of modular multiplicative inverse of A mod B when A > B

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to understand a *Montgomery reduction algorithm*, for which I need to calculate a *multiplicative inverse*.
However, *Euclidean algorithm* only helps if $A < B$.

Example is $11 \mod 3$.
*Multiplicative inverse* of $11$ is $2$,but *ext_gcd* gives you *Bezout* numbers such as -1 and 4.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Wikipedia says so:

> The *extended Euclidean algorithm* is particularly useful when $a$ and $b$ are *coprime*, since $x$ is the modular *multiplicative inverse* of $a$ modulo $b$, and $y$ is the modular *multiplicative inverse* of $b$ modulo $a$.

But as far as I see, this can't be true, either $X$ is *multiplicative inverse* of $A$ modulo $B$ **or** $Y$ is *multiplicative inverse* of $B$ modulo $A$, but not both at the same time, because one of them ($A$ or $B$) is going to be bigger than another. We have $X=4, Y=-1$ for $A=3,B=11$, and $X=4$ is valid inverse, while $-1$ is indeed not.

A lot of online calculators that I tried are also said that a has to be bigger than be, but they (some of them) are still able to calculate inverse of $11 \mod 3$.

The only workaround I found so far is perform $A = A \mod B$ first, so $A$ is now a remainder of divisions and therefore is less than modulus, so we can perform *ext_gcd(2, 3)* now and get our $2$ as answer.

Probably I'm missing something, this thing is pretty new for me.

Thanks.

Comment: "We have X=4, Y=-1 for A=3,B=11, and X=4 is valid inverse, while -1 is indeed not. "  Huh.  $X \equiv A^{-1}\mod  B$ because $X*A = 4*3 \equiv 1 \mod 11$.  An $Y\equiv B^{-1} \mod A$ because $Y*B=(-1)*11 \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  They *are* **both** valid inverses.  What is your issue?

Comment: $-1\equiv 2 \mod 3$.  So $-1$ is *equivalent* to $2$.  It doesn't make the slightest difference which one you use.  (We don't call these things "equivalences" for nothing, you know...)

Comment: "A lot of online calculators that I tried are also said that a has to be bigger than be,"  Calculators don't do mathematics.  Calculators do calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inevitable that a Bézout's identity equation will give you modular multiplicative inverses, since given:

$$am+bn = 1$$

we can take $\bmod m$ for

$$ bn\equiv 1 \bmod m$$

or $\bmod n $ for

$$ am \equiv 1 \bmod n$$

To get $a$ and $b$ in your preferred range, you can simply add or subtract a suitable multiple of the modulus.

So in this case 
$$-1\cdot 11 + 4\cdot 3 = 1$$

and thus
$$-1\cdot 11\equiv 1 \bmod 3$$

($-11$ being one more than $-12$), so $-1$ is a valid inverse of $11$ modulo $3$. Then of course $$-1\equiv 2 \bmod 3$$

so this is consistent with your observation that $2$ is the inverse of $11 \bmod 3$ also.

Comment: I now understand why this is correct from algorithmical point of view, but I don't understand why −1 ≡ 2 mod 3. I miss some math-related thing.

Comment: Presumably you have no problem with $11 \equiv 8\equiv 5 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. In each case, add one and you arrive at a multiple of $3$. The same applies to $-1$.  Also, the difference between $-1$ and $2$ is a multiple of $3$ (as is true for any pair of the equivalent values above).

Answer (score 0):

$-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ so they are considered to be the same thing.

That's we we call these *equivalence* classes.

> However, euclidean algorithm only helps if A < B

I simply do not understand why you say that.

> either X is multiplicative inverse of A modulo B or Y is multiplicative inverse of B modulo A, but not both at the same time, because one of them (A or B) is going to be bigger than another. We have X=4, Y=-1 for A=3,B=11, and X=4 is valid inverse, while -1 is indeed not.

Except, of course, it indeed is.  $-1*11 = -11 \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  That is the valid inverse.  Why do you think it is not?

It doesn't matter if $A > B$ or $B> A$ as $\gcd(A,B) = 1$ Euclid's algorithm will give us:

$mA + kB = 1$ so $k \equiv A^{-1} \mod B$ and $m \equiv B^{-1} \mod A$ simultaneously.

Is your concern that one is represented with a positive number and the other negative?

That's irrelevent.

It doesn't matter *which* representative we use to represent a class.  We could have used $50\equiv -1 \mod 3$ so $50 \equiv 11^{-1}\mod 3$ for all we care.  (Indeed $50*11 = 550 = 3*183 + 1 \equiv 1\mod 3$).

Note: if $mA + kB = 1$ and $m > 0$ but $-A < k < 0$ then

$mA + (k+A)B = 1 + BA\equiv 1 \mod A,B,AB$ and $m$ and $(k+A)$ are still the proper inverses. ANd $m > 0; k+A > 0$.

Indeed $(m + vB)A + (k + uA)B = 1 + (v+u)AB$ so $m + vB\equiv A^{-1} \mod B$ for *any* integer $v$ and $k + uA \equiv B^{-1} \mod A$ for *any* integer $u$.

Comment: "Is your concern that one is represented with a positive number and the other negative?" — Yes, I haven't even considered negative numbers. I'm still not exactly sure how −11 ≡ 1  mod 3. For me logically it looks like quotient of -11/3 is -3, so remainder is either 2 or -2, but how is it 1?

Comment: It looks like a rule to "just take a remainder from division" stops working there. Do I need positive inverse for Montgomery or it doesn't matter?

Comment: $-11 = 3*(-4)+ 1$ so $-11 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $-11 = 3*(-3) -2$ so $-11 \equiv -2 \mod 3$.  And $1 \equiv -2 \mod 3$.  As well $-11 = 3*(-7)+12$ so $-11 \equiv 10 \mod 3$.  But $-11 \ne 3*k + 2$ for any integer $k$ so $-11 \not\equiv 2 \mod 3$.  ***A*** remainder means *any* $p = d*n + r$ and $d$ can be any value positive or a negative and $r$ can be any value that works.  But ***THE*** remainder would mean $p=d*n+r;0\le r< n$ would mean the remainder is unique, positive and less than the divisor.  If $p < 0$ this means $d < 0$ and $r \ge 0$.

Comment: I dont know how to do the Montgomery method.  It seems as though you must already now then inverse to use it and that it is just an computational efficient method to do multiplication.